# Is there any way to trigger php in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a web service and thinking about a knotty problem.

I want a  php script to be executed once there is a change say,insert or update, in mysql. Then the apache server will sent a notification to android client.

Is there a way to do this? Can mysql trigger work?

Comment: Not directly; you'd need to write a UDF that called a shell script to execute the PHP.... this is a highly inefficient approach, prone to failure

Comment: So is there any efficient approach? I just want to sent notification about the change in mysql to android client. @MarkBaker

Comment: Depends what changes your database... if it' scripted changes, then why can't the script that makes the change also send the notification?

Comment: Or you could have a cron job that runs periodically and checks for changes, and notifies android that they've occurred

Comment: write an agent. No one is realistically using udf's

Comment: Thank you. You just remind me @MarkBaker